# CCcomboBoxEx spacing between image and text

Tags: visual-c++, combobox, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

Is there any way, some system metrics value, or anything else that can give how many pixels is the margin between the icon and the image on the CComboBoxEx control?

The space signaled by the red mark in the image below:

[image]

Comment: MFC comes with source. If there isn't anything in the docs, the next thing I would is to look into the source.

Comment: @zett42 I've already looked to the source and could not find any single place where I could know how much is the margin. `CComboBoxEx` implementations are mostly done as a Win32 control which works with messages instead of being a MFC class with its own source exposed.

Comment: I see. I was under the wrong assumption, that `CComboBoxEx` is a MFC control. You are right, it's merely a wrapper around the system control. I don't have any idea how the margin is calculated. It could be hardcoded or a theme property, which are mostly undocumented.

Comment: Maybe raise it as a query to MS?

Comment: Thought - render the item with / without image and with / without indent and compare the differences. The difference should be the gap?